# C# boolean logic with dynamic LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-objects

I've struggle with following task:

Assuming that I have a list with names and values (like a Dictionary). I need to provide user of Web interface a field where he can write a query, checking for existence of specific names and values on that list.

For example, I've got a following list:

```
A = 2, B = 4, D = 0
```

Users want to query this list like that (don't mind syntax, it's just a pseudocode)

- `A == 2 && D` => this returns `true`, as `A` exists and it's value is `2` and `D` also exists.
- `(A && B) || C` => this returns `true`, as both `A` and `B` exists on the list.
- `A && !B` => this returns `false`, as `A` exists on the list but `B` as well (but `B` shouldn't)

I've been looking on dynamic `LINQ`, but it seems that I can evaluate only one object at a time (can't check if object exists on the list and then ask if another one doesn't).
Does anyone knows any materials or links that would be useful?
Thanks

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking for... You can have ORs and ANDs with LINQ...

Comment: You will probably have to implement your own Boolean expression parser; [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17568067/87698) could be a good starting point.

Comment: Why don't you show some code instead of pseudo.. it would be easier to post solutions.

Comment: You can use Expression [Trees to Build Dynamic Queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb882637%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Are users inputting this query as text? Then you need to parse which is hard.

Comment: Yes, user provide this as a text and I need to parse it. More examples? The options are limitless, since I'm looking to cover whole boolean logic. Like (!A && B) || (C || (!D && F) etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, actually Heinzi answered my question, pointing there's a question that answers my problem: [How to parse a boolean expression and load it into a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17568067/how-to-parse-a-boolean-expression-and-load-it-into-a-class)

I've reproduced code provided there and it works flawlessly. No dynamic code (what is far too hard for me), simple binary trees.

Thank you all for the involvement.

Answer (score 3):

not sure whether I have understood your requirement...

is this what you are asking for?

```
Dictionary<string, int> nameValuePairs = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        nameValuePairs.Add("A", 2);
        nameValuePairs.Add("B", 4);
        nameValuePairs.Add("D", 0);


        //A == 2 && D => this returns true, as A exists and it's value is 2 and D also exists
        int d = 0;
        if (nameValuePairs.ContainsKey("A") && nameValuePairs.TryGetValue("D", out d) && nameValuePairs.ContainsKey("D"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test 1: True");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test 1: False");
        }

        //(A && B) OR C => this returns true, as both A and B exists on the list
        if ((nameValuePairs.ContainsKey("A") && nameValuePairs.ContainsKey("B")) || nameValuePairs.ContainsKey("C"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test 2: True");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test 2: False");
        }

        //A && !B => this returns false, as A exists on the list but B as well (but B shouldn't)
        if (nameValuePairs.ContainsKey("A") && !nameValuePairs.ContainsKey("B")) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test 3: True");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test 3: False");
        }
```

Comment: Sorry, Rajes, not really. Your code seems correct, but it must be generated on the fly. These were just examples, as user might come with !A || ((B&&D) || F) and so on. I'm looking for a generic approach.

Answer (score 0):

**Main idea** - you will create **dynamic** code (look at `GenerateCode` function) just as string (it will be analog of your expression) and then compile it to assembly. Then by reflection you will take specific method `Calculate` and execute it. I created `Wrapper` class (each items from dictionary and digits will be wrapped into it), because operations like "&" and "|" impossible implement for `int` type.

**Attention**: Instead of "&&", "OR" you should use "&", "|" tokens or replace them after retrieving from client side before calculating.

**Code:**

```
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static string GenerateCode(Dictionary<string, int> dict, string expres)
        {
            var r = new Regex(@"-?\d+");
            foreach (var item1 in r.Matches(expres))
                expres = expres.Replace(item1.ToString(), string.Format("(new Wrapper({0}))", item1.ToString()));

            r = new Regex("[A-Z]");
            var res = "";
            var areadyDone = new List<string>();

            foreach (var item in r.Matches(expres))
            {
                var key = item.ToString();
                if (!areadyDone.Contains(key))
                {
                    res += string.Format("var {0} = new Wrapper({1});\n", item, dict.ContainsKey(key) ? dict[key].ToString() : "");
                    areadyDone.Add(key);
                }
            }

            return string.Format("{0}return {1};", res, expres);
        }

        public static bool GetAnswer(Dictionary<string, int> dict, string expres)
        {
            string code = @"
using System;

    namespace First
    {

public class Wrapper
    {
        public int value;
        public bool exist = false;
        public Wrapper(int value)
        {
            this.value = value;
            this.exist = true;
        }
        public Wrapper()
        {
        }

        private static bool wrap(Wrapper c1, Wrapper c2, bool cond)
        {
            return (c1 & c2) ? cond : false;
        }

        public static bool operator &(Wrapper c1, Wrapper c2)
        {
            return c1.exist && c2.exist;
        }
        public static bool operator |(Wrapper c1, Wrapper c2)
        {
            return c1.exist || c2.exist;
        }
        public static bool operator !(Wrapper c1)
        {
            return !c1.exist;
        }
        public static implicit operator bool(Wrapper d)
        {
            return d.exist;
        }

        public static bool operator >(Wrapper c1, Wrapper c2)
        {
            return wrap(c1, c2, c1.value > c2.value);
        }
        public static bool operator <(Wrapper c1, Wrapper c2)
        {
            return wrap(c1, c2, c1.value < c2.value);
        }
        public static bool operator >=(Wrapper c1, Wrapper c2)
        {
            return wrap(c1, c2, c1.value >= c2.value);
        }
        public static bool operator <=(Wrapper c1, Wrapper c2)
        {
            return wrap(c1, c2, c1.value <= c2.value);
        }

        public static bool operator ==(Wrapper c1, Wrapper c2)
        {
            return wrap(c1, c2, c1.value == c2.value);
        }
        public static bool operator !=(Wrapper c1, Wrapper c2)
        {
            return wrap(c1, c2, c1.value != c2.value);
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            return base.Equals(obj);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return base.GetHashCode();
        }

    }


        public class Program
        {
            public static bool Calculate()
            {
            " + GenerateCode(dict, expres) + @"
            }

            public static void Main()
            {  
            }

        }
    }";
            var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
            var parameters = new CompilerParameters();

            parameters.GenerateInMemory = true;
            parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;

            var results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, code);
            if (results.Errors.HasErrors)
            {
                var sb = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (CompilerError error in results.Errors)
                    sb.AppendLine(String.Format("Error ({0}): {1}", error.ErrorNumber, error.ErrorText));
                throw new InvalidOperationException(sb.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                var assembly = results.CompiledAssembly;
                var program = assembly.GetType("First.Program");
                var main = program.GetMethod("Calculate");
                return (bool)main.Invoke(null, null);
            }
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            dict.Add("A", 23);
            dict.Add("B", 4);
            dict.Add("F", 5);

            Console.WriteLine(GetAnswer(dict, "(C > -5) | (A >= 10 & B)"));
        }
    }
}
```