# Replace words in String with bool equivalent

Tags: c#

Hi I have to calculate the boolean equivalent for the below string:

```
string rule = "(Func001 AND Func002) AND (Func003 AND Func004)";
```

e.g.:

```
Func001 = true; Func002 = false; Func003 = true; Func004 = true;
```

For this I need to convert all `Func` with their
 boolean result.

Output result be should be:

```
bool i = (true && false) && (true && false);
```

Step 1: used Replace method for operators

```
string modified=  sodrule.Replace("AND", "&&").Replace("OR", "||");
```

Then trying to iterate with all "Func" words, to be replaced with
 boolean equivalent value.

1. The Replace doesnt work.
2. Tried with Stringbuilder class to iterate and then append method.
3. Tried to find Index of Match, and then replace with equivalent boolean

   ```
   string sodrule = "(Func001 AND Func002) AND (Func003 AND Func004)";
   string modified=  sodrule.Replace("AND", "&&").Replace("OR", "||");

   Regex regex = new Regex(@"\b[Func]\w+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);         
   foreach (Match ItemMatch in regex.Matches(modified))
   {
       string R1="R1";
       string functionid = (ItemMatch.Captures[0].Value);
       bool bFunctionID = bool.TryParse(functionid, out bFunctionID);
       bool result = getconflict(functionid, R1);
       modified.Replace(bFunctionID, result);
       int index = modified.IndexOf(functionid);

   }
   Console.WriteLine(modified);

   bool i = true && true && true && true && true && true && true;
   Console.WriteLine(i);
   Console.ReadLine();
   ```

   }

Output result be should be:

```
bool i = (true && false) && (true && false); output ==> false.
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17568067/how-to-parse-a-boolean-expression-and-load-it-into-a-class) can help

Comment: @RaminRahimzada I don't think that's helpful

Comment: What output do you get from this?

Comment: I want to compute the logical operation for that string...
so 1st need to convert to (true && false) && (true && false)

and then compute the value,.... which in this case will be false.

Comment: First, you have a regex, which starts with a word boundary, then a letter (either F, u, n or c), then whitespace. I assume you wanted Func001 in there. Then you try to parse Func001 to a boolean: always false. Then you replace all occurances of 'false' in your string with the result from getconflict. Please just read your code and try again...

Comment: Couple of questions. 1. What does getconflict() function do. 2. What are Func001, Func002, etc. Are they separate variables or array or Dictionary?

Comment: getconflict() function, I just wrote to extract the boolean value for the "FuncXXX" which will be passed as input, some business logic.... can be disregarded...

Func001, Func001, these are functionids, rertieved from DB to make the rule(string).
and this rule needs to be logically computed to extract the boolean result.